# HTTP POST with Parameters and return status code

Tags: c, http, http-post

I am trying to send an HTTP post request to a web API that consumes: application/JSON and has certain parameters: in=body, required = true, type = string and name = name. But I can't figure out how to send the data and make the request with parameters.

```
#define SA struct sockaddr
#define MAXLINE 4096
#define MAXSUB  200


#define LISTENQ 1024

extern int h_errno;

ssize_t process_http(int sockfd, char *host, char *page, char *poststr){
char sendline[MAXLINE + 1], recvline[MAXLINE + 1];
ssize_t n;
snprintf(sendline, MAXSUB,
     "POST %s HTTP/1.0\r\n"
     "Host: %s\r\n"
     "Content-type: application/json\r\n"
     "Content-length: %d\r\n\r\n"
     "%s", page, host, strlen(poststr), poststr);
write(sockfd, sendline, strlen(sendline));
while ((n = read(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
    recvline[n] = '\0';
    printf("%s", recvline);
}
return n;
}

int main(void){
int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

char **pptr;
//********** You can change. Puy any values here *******
char *hname = "some_api_.net";
char *page = "/path";
char *poststr = "in=body&required=true&type=string&name=name\r\n";
//*******************************************************

char str[50];
struct hostent *hptr;
if ((hptr = gethostbyname(hname)) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, " gethostbyname error for host: %s: %s",
        hname, hstrerror(h_errno));
    exit(1);
}
printf("hostname: %s\n", hptr->h_name);
if (hptr->h_addrtype == AF_INET
    && (pptr = hptr->h_addr_list) != NULL) {
    printf("address: %s\n",
           inet_ntop(hptr->h_addrtype, *pptr, str,
             sizeof(str)));
} else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error call inet_ntop \n");
}

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_port = htons(80);
inet_pton(AF_INET, str, &servaddr.sin_addr);

connect(sockfd, (SA *) & servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
process_http(sockfd, hname, page, poststr);
close(sockfd);
exit(0);
}
```

I expect to receive a status code and process it.

Comment: The posted code seems to be a (almost) copy of [original code](http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/code/http_post.c.html)   It is not nice to copy someone elses code and claim it as your own

Comment: regarding: `"POST %s HTTP/1.0\r\n"`   This is the wrong syntax   It should be: `"POST %s HTTP1.0\r\n"  Notice, no `/` after the `HTTP`